# iPhone App: Best Practices to store/retrieve static data

Tags: ios4

I need to load about 500 records of static data to display. I would like to know the best practices to store/retrieve data among using xml file,  array, sqllite using core data in terms of simplicity and performance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you load from xml in plist format into an array,dictionary, set etc, then you have to read it all into memory in one big chunk. If the records are relatively small and simple i.e. no relationships and no custom behaviors, then xml would be the easiest solution.

If memory is an issue and/or the data is complex, then Core Data is the way to go. It not only simplifies memory management but also the interaction with the rest of the app particularly the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Like TechZen said - it depends if you're looking for ease of coding or efficiency/speed.

XML is a pretty standard way - but naturally you'd have to set up a parser for it and any change will mean updating the parser. And speed/efficiency wise each time you'll first load the file into memory and start processing it - so it's not really a fast or efficient solution, but it is pretty simple to implement.

The easiest way to code is to write and read Array with `writeToFile` and `contentsOfFile`.
But arrays and dictionaries are stored as XML files anyway - so you save yourself writing the parser but still won't gain much in terms of speed/performance.

SQLite/CoreData is great for speed and memory and plays well with the rest of the app - but it's overkill if all you're storing is basic data because it takes the most development overhead of the 3 options IMHO.